# ¿Porqué devuelve NULL si en la BD existe un valor?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, sql, variables

Estoy haciendo una cuenta de usuario donde puede ver sus detalles de suscripción.

Al  hacer el pago se le asigna un `ID` único y este valor se inserta correctamente en la tabla de BD `subscriptions`.

El problema viene cuando el usuario accede a su cuenta mediante un link, no se recupera el valor de este `ID` único (`$unique_id`).

Haciendo `var_dump` arroja `NULL` y con otros campos no da `NULL`.

¿Dónde puede estar el fallo?

**index.php**

```
<?php

$sql2 = "SELECT unique_id,status FROM subscriptions";
$result2 = $mysqli->query($sql2);
$row2=$result2->fetch_assoc();
$status= $row2["status"];
$unique_id = $row2["unique_id"];
?>

<li><a href="pago/manage.php?subscription_id=<?php echo $unique_id; ?>">Mi cuenta</a></li>
```

**manage.php**

En esta página deberia  mostrar el valor del `ID` único (`$unique_id`) pero sale `NULL`:

```
 <?php
$sql2 = "SELECT unique_id,status FROM subscriptions";
$result2 = $mysqli->query($sql2);
$row2=$result2->fetch_assoc();
$status= $row2["status"];
$unique_id = $row2["unique_id"];

var_dump($unique_id);
?>
```

[image: Estructura BD[1]]

Comment: puedes mostrar tus registros que tienes en esa tabla? los primeros 5 por decirlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si entiendo bien tu pregunta lo que sucede es cuando regresas por medio del link a el detalle de la subscripción te muestra NULL.

Lo que veo en este código es que en **manage.php** te falta colocar el **WHERE** en tu consulta.

$sql2 = "SELECT unique_id,status FROM subscriptions";

debería estar de la siguiente forma.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT unique_id,status FROM subscriptions WHERE unique_id='id'";
```

con esto recuperara los datos de la transacción que enviaste mediante el link.

Comment: Gracias, probé con tu propuesta pero nada. Probé  WHERE unique_id= '$unique_id'"; y tampoco. La idea es que el usuario logueado hace clik en 'Mi cuenta' con el link: <a href="pago/manage.php?subscription_id=<?php echo $unique_id; ?>">Mi cuenta</a> . Con var_dump($unique_id); da NULL. Mientras que var_dump de otros campos da un resultado . Recientemente hice cambios en .htacces para poner rutas amigables, quizás esté relacionado?

Comment: Probablemente las URL amigables puedan estar interfiriendo, de cualquier manera aunque parezca obvio, asegúrate que estas recogiendo el valor de la url con $_GET[], y que te esta devolviendo el valor requerido.